# SWT:UI updates slowly using display.async and background task in Main thread in Mac/Linux

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, swt

I have a background operation such as copying of upto 3GB data to a desitnation directory. Meanwhile I show a SWT progressbar and a label on the UI which updates asynchronously (`display.asyncExec`). The copy operation is performed inside a new Thread which activates on click of a button. Inside the copy operation I am updating a progressmonitor's `mon.worked()` method, which updates the UI. I am using eclipse's `IProgressMonitor` to create my monitor class.

The copy operation takes hardly 2-3 minutes(MacOsx 10.8.3 8GB Ram, i7) but the UI progress bar is not even half done. The Progress bar shows done only after 5-6 mins.This makes it appear as if the copy operation is taking longer than expected.

I am updating the progress bar as well a label(which displays what file is being copied currently).

I observed that when I update only one component, either ProgressBar or Label then the UI updates quickly.

I don't want to use display.syncexec to as it will take really long and also chances of the UI freezing are high.

Any help/pointers to help me with this issue will be highly appreciated.

Note: Strangely I don't face the issue on Win 7.

Comment: How often are you calling `IProgressMonitor.worked`?

Comment: After copying every single file, I call the IProgressMonitor.worked() API which updates the ProgressBar and the Label(file name) on the UI.

Comment: You might be swamping the queue of `asyncExec` events if there are lots of small files. The Eclipse `Search` results view can suffer from this.

Comment: Can you try calling Display.update() after updating the UI?

Comment: @greg-449 I was able to make the ProgressBar appear faster by updating it less frequently. But I still wonder how it works properly on win 7.

Comment: @GorkemErcan: I tried Display.update() and it did make a difference but when I do it for both the components, the ProgressBar and the label we are back to the same problem.